# Delete a selected row in table when click the delete button

Tags: javascript

I am doing the JS code.

When the user enter their first and last name and click the button "Add Member", their name will appear in the table on the right.

I just don't know how to delete the selected member in the table when user click the "Delete Member".

For example, in this example is to delete the tom,jerry member.

- the user needs to select the row "tom,jerry" then click the button "Delete Member" to delete the selected member.

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3mpd.png)

How can I do the delete function like describe above via JS?

Comment: When the user clicks on a member, give it a class like `selected`. Then you can do `document.querySelector('#memberlist .selected').remove()`

Comment: Replace `#memberlist` with the appropriate selector for the table.

Comment: First of, that's not a *"<table>"*... as far as I can tell from the image. Looks more like a <select multiple> Element. Secondly, please [edit] to include a [mcve]. Read [ask] if in doubt.

Comment: *"How many people are in your group?"* - can't you just count the number of members from the Select element?

Comment: you can use querySelector and the checked option of your select to get the selected option and use remove() to delete it from the select `const selOption = document.querySelector(".members option:checked");
if(selOption)selOption.remove()`

Comment: Use Element.remove() Example: https://jsbin.com/guyoyodosu/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample implementation:

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
<button id="addMember">Add Member</button>
<button id="deleteMember">Delete Member</button>

<table id="memberTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript :

```js
// Function to add a new member to the table
function addMember() {
  const firstNameInput = document.getElementById("firstName");
  const lastNameInput = document.getElementById("lastName");

  const firstName = firstNameInput.value;
  const lastName = lastNameInput.value;

  if (firstName && lastName) {
    const tableBody = document.querySelector("#memberTable tbody");
    const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    newRow.innerHTML = `
      <td>${firstName}</td>
      <td>${lastName}</td>
      <td><button onclick="deleteMember(this)">Delete Member</button></td>
    `;
    tableBody.appendChild(newRow);

    firstNameInput.value = "";
    lastNameInput.value = "";
  }
}

// Function to delete a member from the table
function deleteMember(button) {
  const row = button.parentElement.parentElement;
  row.remove();
}
```

Comment: Can you create just one runnable snippet please?